# Altium 20 pad preview

Tags: altium

In AD19 as far as I remember the pad preview in the footprint editor would show a nice 2D model where we could see the X and Y dimensions (of a rectangle for example) clearly.

With the new AD20 I see this fancy useless 3D preview:
[image]

Does anybody know how to revert back to the 2D view?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask Altium support?

Comment: This was actually something I brought up with one of the devs at the AltiumLive Design Conference in San Diego last October when I got to try AD20 for the first time. I think they were going to add an option to switch between the views, but I can't seem to find it.